# owl Carousel in default opencart theme slider time changing

Tags: jquery, opencart, owl-carousel, opencart2.x

I can't able to change the default slider time between two slides in opencart 2.0.
The slider is owl carousel.
For owl carousel we change the below code for changing the time between slides.

```
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:5000,
```

But that is not working in opencart slider.

Comment: check your version of owl carousel
autoplayTimeout works only in 2.0.0-beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

autoplay: 5000; // values [false, true=3000, seconds]

**Update:**

1. Check the version of **OwlCarousel** that you use, because in different version, the name of option may be different.
2. Find the docs according to your version of **OwlCarousel** or if possible migrate to his newest version.
3. Check docks for ***autoplay*** option name and settings